# AMD drivers which one to install

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx, amd-processor

So i am new to the whole Ubuntu thing and im kinda clueless as to what AMD driver i need to install to run Dota 2 properly because at the moment the HUD flickers whenever i activate an ability or item.

I have three options ATI fire GL, ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (experimental beta), and ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates). If someone could tell me which one is the best to install that'd be awesome. At this time i have the ATI fire GL installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with post-release updates driver. the experimental beta one messed up after reboot and the boot process never got to the login screen. i had to reinstall ubuntu after that.
but my experience was with nvidia.

I wouldnt do beta unless you really know what you are doing. in order to tweak things to make it work. or in a separate install for testing it.

hope this helps a little.

Comment: this is probably more of an advise than an answer. i guess.